# Vite with Jest: cannot find module start with alias '@'

Tags: jestjs, vue-test-utils, vite

I'm using Jest in Vite. It works until I import a module from node_module.

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useCookies } from '@vueuse/integrations/useCookies'
```

I got this error.

```
 FAIL  src/components/MyComponent/index.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@vueuse/integrations/useCookies' from 'src/components/MyComponent/index.vue'

    Require stack:
      src/components/MyComponent/index.vue
      src/components/MyComponent/index.test.ts

      16 | <script lang="ts">
      17 | import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    > 18 | import { useCookies } from '@vueuse/integrations/useCookies'
         | ^
      19 |
      20 | export default defineComponent({

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
```

I guess somehow Jest cannot resolve the module starts with '@'. Maybe I should write a moduleNameMapper? I also tried to install vite-jest, but somehow my app just crash, maybe I mess up something.

Anyway, thanks for your time, and if you need more information like my jest.config.js or vite.config.ts, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4262, yet I wasn't using mock so I'm not sure if this is the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) in your `jest.config.js` file like following:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
};
```

Also, if you are using TypeScript, you should add the following to your `tsconfig.json` file as well:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src"]
    }
  }
}
```